# [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK]Base.apk is missing with Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

Not sure if this is the correct place for this but I have no idea what is happening.

I have installed Visual Studio, selected the `Xamarin.Form` development option. I then created a blank app called AwesomeApp. When I create ANY android simulator, I get the below error:

> ADB0010:  Deployment failed Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException:
>   Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Package couldn't be installed in
>   /data/app/com.companyname.awesomeapp-n7s-TVkN9lE8v1nea3tFZg==: Package
>   /data/app/com.companyname.awesomeapp-n7s-TVkN9lE8v1nea3tFZg==/base.apk
>   code is missing]

Has anyone experience this or even found a way around this? Following the suggestions only, such as cleaning the project, solution and rebuilding are not working. This happens with any project, no matter of the name or naming convention (i.e AwesomeApp or awesomeapp)

Comment: Try to delete the application on your device,and then redeploy.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT The app doesn't show on the device. I've tried creating multiple emulators of different configuration and nothing is working :/

Comment: Does restarting the adb service work ?

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT Restarting and recreating brand new virtual phones didn't help. restarting the computer doesn't help. reinstalling VS and the emulator doesn't help. FYI Flutter apps build and run without an issue on the virtual devices.I'm really at a loss! :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For me it's fixed by changing Dex Compiler from dx to d8 and disabling Shared Mono Runtime & Multi Dex

Upd:
A bit late but disabling Shared Mono Runtime is optional. Found out that it also works with it.

Comment: Do you have any resources for performing these changes? I have no idea where these settings would be :-)

Comment: Right click on your droid project -> Options -> Build -> Android build. Make sure you are editing right configuration and platform

Comment: how change it ?!!

Comment: @MoshtabaDarzi Have you seen my comment above?

Comment: how can change dx to d8 and disabling Shared Mono Runtime & Multi Dex ?
im new in react native , tnx

Comment: @MoshtabaDarzi sorry but I have no idea about react native. I posted an answer for Xamarin.Android/Xamarin.Forms

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your project back to the current recommended defaults. Remove all of the following properties from the .csproj file:

- AndroidEnableMultiDex
- AndroidDexGenerator
- AndroidLinkTool
- AndroidDexTool

This will let Xamarin.Android pick the current latest default values.